# How to hide everything except the text between the inner square brackets in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, xml, translation

I got xml file in which I need to translate text between the inner square brackets. It's a huge file with thousands of inner square brackets with the texts for translation.

Is there a way to hide everything except the text between the inner square brackets in Notepad++?

For example here:

```
...item name="wcf.conversation.attachments"><![CDATA[Conversation contains {#$conversation->attachments} attachment{if $conversation->attachments != 1}s{/if}]]></item>...
```

Ideally I want to hide everything except "`Conversation contains attachment`", translate this text, and when I will translate all these texts, I want to unhide everything.

Or do you know any other way to make the translation process easier and quicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It's a bit late, but...*

---

> Or do you know any other way to make the translation process easier and quicker?

If you RegEx search <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for:

```
<\!\[CDATA\[\K.*(?=\]\]><\/item>)
```

and close the "Find" dialog:

[image: Npp RegEx search]

You can look for "text between the inner square brackets" in your file with just "Find Next" <kbd>F3</kbd>. Text you're looking for will be selected, ready to replace with each "Find Next" call.

Comment: g2mk, Thank you very much. This is a real help to me.

Comment: @Killerwhale7 So maybe... https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I voted on your answer, and a message appeared saying that I have less than 15 reputation so my vote is recorded but not displayed.
I accepted your answer.

Comment: g2mk, is there a way to select only the text outside of curly brackets, only "Conversation contains attachment" without "{#$conversation->attachments}" and "{if $conversation->attachments != 1}s{/if}"?

Comment: @Killerwhale7 What's about `s` in `{if $conversation->attachments != 1}s{/if}`? It is also placed outside of curly brackets. What are you doing with `{#$conversation->attachments}`, `{if $conversation->attachments != 1}`, `{/if}` after translation? Are yu keep it or delete it? Is text to translate provided in place of `{#$conversation->attachments}` and you want just get rid of `Conversation contains` and `attachment`, or something other. You should clarify you question a bit. Please do it by editing your question using [markdown](https://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: g2mk, it's just that I sometimes get these .xml files to translate what is inside square brackets. If you'll give me your email, I'll send you one of these files. I should just translate what is inside the square brackets and I should not touch formulas, I should just leave them as they are. I don't know if "s" should be translated or not, whether I should translate "attachment" or "attachments". I've never done these translations before. Maybe you can tell me if "s" should be translated or not.